# app upload picture to specific album without posting on page wall

Tags: facebook, post, image

How to post a picture to a specific album in page from app without posting the image on page wall? Currently I can post picture to a specific album, but I don't want to see that on page wall becouse the app will post a lot of pictures. So how that is possible?

This is an example of app that uploads generated picture to specific album but dosn't publish it on its wall, I'm trying to do the same.
http://www.facebook.com/MercedesBenz?sk=app_318742408161371

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible by providing `no_story` parameter equal to `1` while uploading photo.

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/ALBUM_ID/photos?no_story=1
```

This information once was documented for `photo` object, but not anymore exists in current documentation.

This is described in Developer Blog post: [Suppressing auto-generated feed stories when uploading photos](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/482/)